# Accurate date formats based on Carbon dates

Tags: php, laravel, timezone, php-carbon

I've been trying to solve the issue for my database data saved from Amazon API. The data is being fetched using cron job with a predefined date range starting from previous year up to June 2021.
My issue is, I can't get the accurate results using the Laravel carbon date. I am not sure what exactly I did wrong. On some date range, I can get the accurate result, but when I change dates, the result is not correct. So for example when I query the data from June 1 - June 30, I can get an exact result and I can confirm it by comparing the result using the same date range when fetching the data directly from the Amazon API, but when I change it let's say to June 5-June 22, the result is no longer accurate. I suspect it's because of the wrong date format I used but honestly I don't know the correct format to use. I tried many formats, but failed. Here is the example date format returned from Amazon

1. 2021-06-18T14:35:33+00:00
2. 2021-06-18T15:08:11+00:00

By default, laravel's timezone use `'timezone' => 'UTC'` globally in config file.
My user lives in Berlin, Germany so I use Europe/Berlin when I query the database

I tried the following:

```
          $start = Carbon::parse("$from Europe/Berlin")->tz('UTC')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
          $end = Carbon::parse("$to Europe/Berlin")->endOfDay()->tz('UTC')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Then I used it to query table, something like

```
          ->whereBetween('purchase_date',[$start,  $end])
```

I also tried to format the returned date from amazon like

```
   Carbon::parse($value['date'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

And also tried to save it as is (meaning just save it to field, the field type is datetime)

My questions are,

1. how do you format the date using laravel carbon to get accurate result
2. Currently my default user lives in Berlin/Germany, if a user is added from different place and timezone, how do you dynamically adjust the date formatting?
3. The user's date(timepicker) is based on local date, is it possible that this is the reason why I can't get accurate result?

*UPDATE:*

**After comparing monthly time ranges for years 2020-2021 ex --month=June --year=2021 , --month=March --year=2020, I noticed that month of June for both 2020 and 2021 has the inconsistent results. Other months are perfectly fine. This confused me anew.**

Comment: Try this  `$start  = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $from, 'Europe/Berlin')->setTimezone('UTC');`

Comment: What is `$from` and `$to`? You can just pass Carbon instances directly to `whereBetween()` and it will convert accordingly.

Comment: $from and $to is the dates supplied by user. example $from => 2021-06-01 - $to => 2021-06-23